# Nutch and Elasticsearch index template alias

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I've been searching and reading and it seems like Nutch 1.10 does not support Elasticsearch 1.5 index template alias? Is that correct and if so, if I need that support, do I need to use Nutch 2.x branch?